# Is there any ORM tools on google app engine (Java)?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

everyone. I used Ruby and Rails before, and I enjoy Rails's ORM, which make me develop application very fast... ...(also make me reduce lots of SQL statement.) But now, I need to move from ROR to Google App Engine. Is there any ORM tools on that? Also, I heart that Google have some amazing tools called "Google Web Toolkit", can I take advance of this tools within any setup? Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT is not a ORM tool by any stretch of imagination. You can check JDO or JPA for GAE applications built using GWT. My personal favorite is Objectify, a perfect balance between native API and JDO. YMMV

If you are not particular of language, have you considered Python + Django?

Answer (score 0):

I've been lead developer for mardao, https://github.com/sosandstrom/mardao/wiki/Quick for three years now, and it is a combined ORM and Dao generator. You run it as a maven plugin at build-time, it scans your JPA-annotated domain objects and generates DAOs for you, using the Low-level API of the Datastore. No classpath scanning or reflection is used run-time!
It is in stable production maturity (version 2.3.0) and available in Maven Central.